# perform calculation in df based on changing columns daily in df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, operators

I want to perform a calculation in pandas based on values in another column. this has been covered before however the problem i have is my columns appear or are removed daily as my values change daily ie if there is a value in the column then the column remains in the df otherwise the column is removed.
example dataset is below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2],
                   'b': [0.5, 0.75]}
                   'fast add': ['ADD', '')
                   'fast del': ['', 'DEL'])

df['move needed'] = df['a'] / df['b']
```

i only want to perform this calc in the rows which have ADD for the fast add column and/or DEL for the fast del column. i cant use the OR operator in np.where because sometimes the fast del column for example is empty for every row and therefore deleted so you only have fast add column and vice versa. hope someone can help me with this

Comment: I still do not really understand why you cannot use `np.where`

Comment: for example if use np.where((df['fast add'] = 'ADD') | (df['fast del'] = 'DEL')). that will work only if both columns are present in the dataframe but sometimes fast aa coloum or fast del column wont be present as it is empty so its removed from the dataframe. therefore when i run np.where the code breaks looking for fast add column

Comment: write a function that checks for the columns you want... if ADD and DEL are present in the frame then do np.where else do whatever else you do when they are not present. You have not told us what you want to do to the data if a column is not present in the frame

Comment: thank chris sorry but i am still very new to pyhton do you have an example of a fuction to check if the fast add and delete columns are present in my df? if they are not i dont want any calc to be prefromed and the move needed column should be left blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below. It is not a best solution if your dataset if big.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'a': [1, 2,3],
                   'b': [0.5, 0.75,1],
                   'fast add': ['ADD', '',''],
                   'fast del': ['', 'DEL','']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fast_add_check = list(df.columns).count('fast add') # Check if column exist
fast_del_check = list(df.columns).count('fast del') # Check if column exist

if fast_add_check> 0 and fast_del_check  > 0:
    df.loc[df['fast add'] == 'ADD', 'move needed'] = df['a']/df['b']
    df.loc[df['fast del'] == 'DEL', 'move needed'] = df['a']/df['b']
elif fast_add_check> 0 and fast_del_check  == 0:
    df.loc[df['fast add'] == 'ADD', 'move needed'] = df['a']/df['b']
elif fast_add_check == 0 and fast_del_check > 0:
    df.loc[df['fast del'] == 'DEL', 'move needed'] = df['a']/df['b']

df['move needed'].fillna('', inplace=True) #treat nan values as needed
```

Comment: thank you but this works if both columns fast add and delete are present. when i run my code tomorrow for example the fast delete column may not be present so this code will break as it doesnt reconize that column in the df. any suggestions?